# Linq join three tables orderd by Timstamp

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2012, entity-framework-5

I have three tables:

```
Sites:
Id
Timezone (string)
SiteName

Vehicles:
Id
SiteId
Name

Positions:
Id
TimestampLocal (DateTimeOffset)
VehicleId
Data1
Data2
...
Data50
```

There are multiple positions for a single vehicle. The position table is very large (100+ mil. records)
I need to get the last position for each vehicle (by timestamp as they can send old data) and its timezone so I can do further data processing based on the timezone. Something like **{PositionId, VehicleId, Timezone, Data1}**

I have tried with:

```
var result = 
from ot in entities.Positions
join v in entities.Vehicles on ot.VehicleId equals v.Id
join s in entities.Sites on v.SiteId equals s.Id
group ot by ot.VehicleId into grp
select grp.OrderByDescending(g=>g.TimestampLocal).FirstOrDefault();
```

then I process the data with:

```
foreach (var rr in result){... update Data1 field ...    }
```

This gets the last values but it does bring all the fields in Positions (a lot of data) and no Timezone. Also the foreach part is very CPU intensive (as it probably brings the data) as it gets 100% CPU for a few seconds).

How can this be done in Linq ...and be lightweight for the DB and its transfers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following it is on same lines as you have done but the result contains `Sites` `Timezone`column as projected, it is projected in the Join itself

```
var result =
S.Join(V,s1=>s1.Id,v1=>v1.SiteId,(s1,v1)=>new {v1.Id,s1.Timezone})
 .Join(P,v1=>v1.Id,p1=>p1.VehicleId,(v1,p1)=>new {p1,v1.Timezone})
 .GroupBy(g=>g.p1.VehicleId)
 .Select(x=>x.OrderByDescending(y=>y.p1.TimestampLocal).FirstOrDefault())
 .Select(y=>new {y.p1,y.Timezone});
```

Now following are important points related to the questions you have asked:

1. To reduce the number of columns fetched, as you may not want all the Positions columns, following need to be done:

   - In this line - `Join(P,v1=>v1.Id,p1=>p1.VehicleId,(v1,p1)=>new {p1,v1.Timezone})`
     project the fields, which are result of the Join, something like:

     ```
     new {p1.Id,p1.TimestampLocal,p1.VehicleId,p1.Data1,p1...,v1.Timezone}
     ```

     which will provide only the projected field, but then the `GroupBy` would change to   `GroupBy(g=>g.VehicleId)`
2. Other option for the same would be change the GroupBy projection, as follows instead of Join statement

   ```
   GroupBy(g=>g.p1.VehicleId, 
   g=>new {g.p1.Id,g.p1.TimestampLocal,g.p1.VehicleId,g.p1.Data1,g.p1...,g.Timezone})
   ```
3. Now the remaining part process being CPU intensive and using 100% CPU, following could be done to optimize:

   - Does each `foreach` loop iterations does the network `Update` call, then it is bound to make it a network intensive process and thus slow, preferable would be doing all the necessary changes in-memory and then updating the database in one go that would still be intensive if you have millions of record

Even doing the same for million records will never be a good idea, since that would be a fairly network and CPU intensive, thus making it slow, your options would be:

- Chunk the memory into smaller components, since I am not sure if any one needs to update million records in one shot, so make it multiple smaller updates, which are executed one after another triggered by the user, but will be much less taxing on the system resources.
- Bring smaller dataset in the memory, do the filtering at the database level using a parameter and pass the necessary data for modification in memory to update.
- Using projection as shown in the Linq above, bring only the required columns, that would reduce overall data memory footprint, bound to have an impact.
- If the logic is such that various updates are mutually exclusive, then do them using Parallel API in a thread safe structure, that would ensure efficient and quick CPU utilization of all the cores, thus faster, though it will spike to 100% CPU but to a fraction of the Non parallel execution

Beside this provide me specific details to help you our with more details, these are basic suggestions, there's no golden rule to solve such optimization issues

Comment: Thank you. Good suggestions. I will project only the minimum number of fields to minimize footprint. The update is done in one call after all the modifications (outside the foreach). Should I go for an insert (with updated values) instead of update? Would that be less costly?